# to display one models data in other models view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

in my rails3 app i have two controller leaves and leave_request and the corresponding models.Their migrations are :

leaves table:

```
 class CreateLeaves < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def self.up
        create_table :leaves do |t|
          t.integer :user_id
          t.integer :company_id
          t.string  :leave_type
          t.integer :allowed_leaves
          t.text :description, :limit => 500

          t.timestamps
        end
      end

      def self.down
        drop_table :leaves
      end
    end
```

leave_requests table:

```
class CreateLeaveRequests < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :leave_requests do |t|
      t.integer :employee_id
      t.integer :leave_type
      t.date :from_date
      t.date :to_date
      t.text :reason_for_leave
      t.string :contact_during_leave, :limit => 10
      t.integer :leave_balance
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :company_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :leave_requests
  end
end
```

and in view:

```
 <!-- Right column/section -->
    <aside class="column width2" >
      <p ><a href="/leave_requests" class="btn btn-special btn-green"><img SRC="images/add.png" class="icon" alt=""/>View All Requests </a></p>&nbsp;
       <div class = "zebra-sriped">
                   <table  width="300">
                         <tr>   
                            <th colspan="1">Leave</th>
                                          <th colspan="1">Balance</th>
                         </tr>
                     <tbody>
                         <tr> 
                                          <th><%= Leave.find(@leave.leave_type).leave_type %>></th>
                                            <th> <%= Leave.find(@leave.leave_type).allowed_leaves %></th>    
                   </tr>
                             </tbody>
                 </table>
                </div>                

     </aside>
    <!-- End of Right column/section -->
```

I created few leave types ex: annual, vacation, paid,  unpaid etc. Number of allowed_leaves also save manually.Now i want to show leave_types(read only) and their number of allowed_leaves(read only) at the time of a user create a leave request and at the end validate the leave allowed i.e. user can't request leave more than allowed.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is an association between these two models then you should declare that in the model.

For example, if each Leave had many LeaveRequests then you would do the following:

```
# app/models/leave.rb
class Leave < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :leave_requests
end

# app/models/leaverequest.rb
class LeaveRequest < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :leave
end
```

Then you could access the leave_requests from anywhere via Leave.new.leave_requests or leave from anywhere via LeaveRequest.new.leave.

Comment: Hi Rupert thanks again. But this did not solve my query.I just want to show leave_types and relative allowed day's from leave model in leave_request form.